# Jar execute on android

Tags: android

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, "com.example.delphijar.SubActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}
}
```

I want when button click, jar file execute.
jar only hello world text.

com.example.delphijar.SubActivity is jar .

but `cannot resolve constructor  'intent(anonymous android.view.View,OnClickListener, java,lang,string' error

How coding intent part ?